# multiplication table of matrices

Tags: matrices

I would like to create a multiplication table of Pauli matrices to show that multiplying 2 Pauli matices results in a quaternion.  What would be the best way to do that?

Comment: You should post this to https://tex.stackexchange.com/.

Comment: No its for a wiki. I dont know latex and the wiki doesn't use latex. It uses the same notation you use on math stackexchange. And I thought people would appreciate the interesting math relationship here between PaulI matrices and quaternions.

Comment: To make it legible I would assign each matrix to a letter and then make your multiplication table using the letters from these assignments.

Comment: Thank you Rob. That's exactly what I was looking for.

Comment: I've had a go at it using an array environment. If you want all the matrices to have the same aspect ratio, then you could create each of them using an array environment wrapped in \left( and \right) with separate columns for the signs and the digits.

Comment: My pleasure. You are a bit off-topic here, but it's always fun to see how good MathJax is. @DougM: I half agree with you, but it's a lot easier to check the multiplication table if it contains the actual matrices. So I'd advise the OP to give both forms of the table (and perhaps to rephrase the question as a request for the best way to present the mathematical information the table contains).

Answer (score 1):

Thank you Rob Arthan

$\begin{array}{c|c|c|c}
& \begin{pmatrix} 
      0&1\\
      1&0
\end{pmatrix}
& \begin{pmatrix} 
      0&-i\\
      i&0
\end{pmatrix}
& \begin{pmatrix}
      1&0\\
      0&-1
\end{pmatrix} \\\hline
\begin{pmatrix}  
      0&1\\
      1&0
\end{pmatrix}
& \begin{pmatrix} 
      1&0\\
      0&1
\end{pmatrix}
& \begin{pmatrix}
      i&0\\
      0&-i
\end{pmatrix}
& \begin{pmatrix}
      0&-1\\
      1&0
\end{pmatrix} \\\hline
\begin{pmatrix} 
      0&-i\\
      i&0
\end{pmatrix}
& \begin{pmatrix} 
      -i&0\\
      0&i
\end{pmatrix}
& \begin{pmatrix}
      1&0\\
      0&1
\end{pmatrix}
& \begin{pmatrix}
      0&i\\
      i&0
\end{pmatrix} \\\hline
\begin{pmatrix} 
      1&0\\
      0&-1
\end{pmatrix}
& \begin{pmatrix} 
      0&1\\
      -1&0
\end{pmatrix}
& \begin{pmatrix}
      0&-i\\
      -i&0
\end{pmatrix}
& \begin{pmatrix}
      1&0\\
      0&1
\end{pmatrix} \\
\end{array}$

$\begin{array}{c|c|c|c}
& \sigma_1
& \sigma_2
& \sigma_3 \\\hline
\sigma_1
& 1
& i
& -j \\\hline
\sigma_2
& -i
& 1
& k \\\hline
\sigma_3
& j
& k
& -1 \\
\end{array}$